# HTML Form POST Cross Domain

Tags: html, post, cross-domain

I have a very simple HTML form that uses POST and its action calls a PHP script on my web server.

Here is the kicker... the html that contains the form isn't hosted on the same server and exists in a different domain.  Without bogging down this question with explanation this has to be done for business reasons.  They need to exist within these specific domains.

When I submit my form I access the PHP script correctly but then I try and pull out the POST data and it is gone.  I'm thinking this is a security problem because I temporarily put the form on the same server as the PHP and it worked fine.

Is there a way that I can get this to work with the two separate domains?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:

PHP Code (emailTemplate.php):

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form name="emailForm" id="emailForm" method="post" onsubmit="return beforeSubmit();" action="https://***.***.com/emailTemplate.php">
    <textarea rows="15" cols="75" id="myHtmlText" name="myHtmlText"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="toAddr" name="toAddr" size="60"/>
    <input type="text" id="fromAddr" name="fromAddr" size="60"/>
    <input type="text" id="subjectLine" name="subjectLine" size="60"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Email Letter">
</form>
```

Comment: Theoretically, what you're doing shouldn't cause any problems. It sounds like (a) there's an error in the PHP script receiving the POST data or in the webform sending it, or there's some sort of security measure in place in your PHP script or server configuration that is blocking the post. Unfortunately, the best we can do is speculate unless you can post some of your code.

Comment: Seems to work if Firefox but not IE.  IE gives an XSS warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only experiencing the issue in IE, their XSS filter may be to blame. [This article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/how-do-i-fix-cross-site-scripting-it-comes-up/eafedfa5-ab47-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2?tab=AllReplies#tabs) provides details for disabling it.

To avoid this problem entirely, try posting your form to a PHP script on your server, and in that script, create a cURL session that posts the form to the other script. The XSS transaction occurs independently of the client's web browser, averting these browser-based security restrictions in the process.

Comment: This won't work if the result contains any relative URLs. The client will interpret those URLs relative to your domain, not the remote domain.